# Typescript generic type inferences is `any` for function after changing object shape

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

Is it possible in typescript to infer function parameters after changing function object shape?
The idea here is to generate redux actions creators types dynamically from function parameters. This generally works until you don't need to use generic types. In the example below i want to generate action payload

```js
export function createActionFactory<
  R extends string,
  T extends any[],
  P extends object
>(type: R, payloadCreator: (...args: T) => P) {
  const actionCreator = (...args: T) => {
    const payload = payloadCreator(...args);

    return { type, payload };
  };

  // comment to get proper type inference
  actionCreator.toString = () => type;

  return actionCreator;
}

// Let's assume react component
type ComponentType<P = {}> = { props: P };
const ModalComponent: ComponentType<{ foo: string, closeModal?: () => void }> = { props: { foo: "bar" } };

const show = createActionFactory(
  "SHOW",
  <T extends { closeModal?: () => void }>(
    component: ComponentType<T>,
    props: Omit<T, "closeModal">
  ) => ({ component, props })
);

// should fail as `quz` is not in the props
show(ModalComponent, { quz: "bar" });
```

**Typescript playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAEENsUAxQjaATwB4AoOOAJTlBJQBMBnOPxhRMKAOYAaVnAAqXEDwFxCKegG0AutLYAFBUsEQARgCtgGZgD4AFDHphgALg6S4YQvQA2EQrwDCBMTQLjYAdBGEUOL8LrIAlHAAvFZwuokA3jJoOMIqFDiBRDDQyXDhkdGxcokpcFlsbDkoeR7evrxlbT5+RcFQFWFRMfEA3MwybAQwSFC4GXD2jm7dHXAAvuNsmxNsAPR7eBAAtsfAKPAlcOLA8GBQEI5Qiw7AcGIIwATowDK0WIUgiUoGESgBlERicRlGy1VJLYDjGTTWa4f6UPrA8brCYHOAAGVuAHJBIR+PwkGc4EEMEdjpAUOcYMwEXB-CcGUzZK9GPokvV1ql+Qt7o9qvods08gBZCC8Qhedn0nBMlxKzkXbmORgLBAQCAuYSiCRuNA+fjAWXyrwAflCcLgADcIJhOoKyiKHmBqrr9S4AETGKL+jYbJFS+D8AAWEAA7mV8MUyAVqP8GDYZP6wQAJADyAHV-To4Ix5NxzsoFmaIBarQq7eUHc7XRtbJM6RqYGqOSrNTzZFZi2xRd6XLnjpgYKW3P7q7W5Qr-VYZA6bFWe4yLisvYJ1vFmGNcYdoxAkF5OghCJgvCpBAADACOSAAXnf3oIUBB4GJFlG3iP+GYE9YxsOtFQ3Jk3AWJ9nwDIMoBDPdxiAA)**.

Comment: what should `show` accept as a parameter. Just something that has `closeModal` ?Or something that can have other props ?

Comment: If you call it like this (http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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) you get an error. Not sure if ok

Comment: Interestingly, @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's snippet on sandbox shows a different type inference result

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko It's different because i don't pass in a generic function as the payload creator. Not sure what the intent of that was ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir this works, but for this specific case, i need to use generics. Please have a look at an updated example :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir from what I see, this is something typescript didn't support as after adding the new property to the object it just loses all generic information

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir any thoughts? Maybe it's worth to fill an issue inside TS repo?